# Why is the determinant of the 5-2 knot not a multiple of 5?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

A knot $K$ is $p$-colorable if and only if the det($K$) is divisible by $p$.

So why is the |det($5_2$)| $=7$, and not a multiple of 5, especially when there are only 5 arcs in the knot?

Comment: If you write out what the definition of 5-colorability is, you might answer your question. It's more subtle than 3-colorability, so it pays to be careful.

Comment: Ah I see it now, thanks. That is sneaky.

So the mathematical definition of p-colorability is a different idea compared to physically coloring the arcs, even though that is where the mathematical definition stems from.

Comment: It's pretty common for a "coloring" in math to mean a configuration of abstract colors associated to an object subject to some constraints. But, like everything in math, you can't know what a word means unless you check the specific definition you're working with. (By the way, $p$-colorability of knots comes from Ralph Fox making the study of dihedral representations of knot groups accessible to undergraduates. It's nice how something seemingly abstruse ends up being relatively easy to explain.)